# Log-Subharmonicity of the Bergman Kernel

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, bergman-spaces

I am currently reading a paper in wich the author shows the subharmonicity of the Bergman kernel on the diagonal with respect to the weightfunction of the Bergman space. The statement I am struggling with is **the following**:

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be some smooth, subharmonic function, such that
\begin{equation}
e^{g(z)}f(z)
\end{equation}
is subharmonic for every smooth, subharmonic function $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\log f$ also is subharmonic.

**So far I tried** to calculate the Laplacian $\Delta \log f$ using the identity
\begin{equation}
\log f = \log (e^g f) - g,
\end{equation}
but there are always terms that I can not find good bounds of. Also I thougt one could find some approximation of $\log f$ by subharmonic functions, but I dont't think that actually works.

Any hints would be helpful. Thanks a lot.